# Add new columns

Tags: scala

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCr45.png)Hi I am trying to a new column to a Spark. I am trying in a data set where I want to add the percentage made by in all games.
The data set looks like this:

Name,   Platform,   Year,   Genre,  Publisher,  NA_Sales,   EU_Sales,   JP_Sales,   Other_Sales

```
val vgdataLines = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/ashhall1616/bdc_data/t1/vgsales-small.csv")
val vgdata = vgdataLines.map(_.split(";"))
def toPercentage(x: Double): Double = {x * 100} val countPubl  = vgdata.map(r =>  (r(4),1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
val addpercen = countPubl.withColumn("count", toPercentage($"count"/countPubl.count(_._2)))
```

I used `withColumn()` to add new column 'count' and expected output to be like:

`(Ubisoft,3,15.0)`

Can anyone tell whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use "withColumn" with an RDD.
You could do as follow

```
val addpercen = countPubl.map({case(key, value) => (key, value, toPercentage(value))})
```

use map to add a calculated value as new column and convert to a DataFrame if you want

```
import spark.implicits._
val myDf = addpercen.toDF("key","value","myNewColumn") 

myDf.show()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `withColumn` with an RDD hence convert it to DataFrame as below and then use it

```
val countPubl : DataFrame  = vgdata.map(r =>  (r(4),1)).reduceByKey(_+_).toDF()
```

If you still looking to use RDD then just converto it back to RDD once you add the with column as

```
val javaRdd : JavaRDD[Row] = countPubl.withColumn("...",col("...")).toJavaRDD
```

Comment: Okay but what if I want to use the same logic in RDD?

Comment: `scala> val javaRdd : JavaRDD[Row] = countPubl.withColumn("count", toPercentage($"count"/countPubl.count(_._2))).toJavaRDD
<console>:32: error: not found: type JavaRDD
       val javaRdd : JavaRDD[Row] = countPubl.withColumn("count", toPercentage($"count"/countPubl.count(_._2))).toJavaRDD
                     ^`

Comment: `<console>:32: error: value withColumn is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]
       val javaRdd : JavaRDD[Row] = countPubl.withColumn("count", toPercentage($"count"/countPubl.count(_._2))).toJavaRDD
                                              ^`

Comment: `<console>:32: error: too many arguments for method count: ()Long
       val javaRdd : JavaRDD[Row] = countPubl.withColumn("count", toPercentage($"count"/countPubl.count(_._2))).toJavaRDD
                                                                                                       ^`

Comment: add my first line and then use the second

Comment: can't get it 'add my first line and then use the second'

Comment: you dint even convert RDD to dataframe before using withColumn
my 1st line of code does it for you once your done add tyhe column using the second line  and replace the appropriate column names and funcs